# Как задать ширину одного элемента на экране 50% ширины экрана

Tags: java, android

Как в xml файле для кнопки указать ширину - 50% от ширины устройства?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_add"
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in" />
```

Пробую вот так:, создаётся на весь экран

```
<android.widget.LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_add"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in" />
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не работает sumWeight, ругается что такого не существует!

Comment: Прошу прощения, weightSum, а не sumWeight

Answer (score 2):

Не так давно Google представила новую библиотеку [`support:persent`](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/), которая реализует два контейнера:`PersentRelativeLayout` и `PersentFrameLayout` - данные контейнеры не отличаются от таких же из SDK ничем, кроме как тем, что позволяют указывать значения для вложенных элементов в процентах - вы можете использовать эту библиотеку.

Что же касается ваших попыток получить половину размера, то способ этот тоже вполне рабочий. Ошибка ваша в том, что если не указан параметр `weightSum`, вычисление весов элементов в контейнере осуществляется по сумме весов для каждого элемента контейнера, разделенную на долю конкрентного веса элемента.
У вас один элемент с весом .5 , сумма весов в этом контейнере - .5, следовательно этот элемент займет всю доступную ширину, что мы и видим.

Решений два: указать параметр `weightSum` в два раза больше (так как вы хотите 50%) веса элемента, в вашем случае - 1, либо поставить рядом с кнопкой виджет-пустышку `Space` с таким же значением веса (для получения по 50% на каждого).
В этом вопросе (о весах элементов) еще есть такое мнение, что целые числа упрощают расчеты, поэтому мы укажем для весов целые значения - 1( два элемента с весом по 1 - общий вес равен 2, каждому по 50% размера контенера).

1 вариант:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weghtSum="2">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_add"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:text="@string/action_sign_in" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

2 вариант:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_add"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:text="@string/action_sign_in" />
     <Space
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"   />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".50" />
```

**UPD**

Или так:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight=".5">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не работает! =(

Comment: основной layout linearLayout?

Comment: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Поместите кнопку в LinearLayout, который в свою очередь будет лежать в CoordinatorLayout, и имеющий width="match_patent". Должно работать по идее

Comment: Она создаётся во весь экран, в шапку добавил код как пробую

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте